# Determine if Popup is in foreground of Excel

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop

I'm writing a VSTO add-in for Excel and I have noticed that if I lock the sheet and password protect it (so only my add-in can write to it but the user can view it), if the user tries to edit the sheet they get the "This sheet is locked" popup.  If while that prompt is still pending user input, the add-in tries to write to the sheet, Excel crashes.  The act of writing to the sheet involves unprotecting it, writing the data, then locking it again.  The Add-in captures data from an external source via the serial port so data could be written at any time.

To recreate:
1. Lock sheet with add-in.
2. User attempts to edit sheet contents
3. User is prompted that they cannot edit the contents of the sheet because it is locked.
4. Data comes in the serial port and the add-in attempts to unlock, write data, and lock the sheet before the user has a chance to ack the prompt that was thrown.
5. Excel bytes the dust.

Any suggestions?  I was toying with the idea of maintaining a hidden "master" sheet and the visible sheet and just using an excel formula or named range to reference the hidden sheet.  However this would then be open to editing and potential data corruption by a user.  The data must be as un-editable as possible.

Update: I would be satisfied with catching the COMException so it doesn't kill excel, however the general "catch (Exception ex)" doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was apparently

```
catch(Exception)
```

does not function as a general catch all when it comes to a COMException.  Adding the line

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

and then adding

```
catch(COMException)
```

to my try...catch blocks allows me to handle the errors better.  Mix that with some code to retry the failed action a few times after using

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
```

seems to make things better.  However, blindly sending the escape key to the forefront program can cause some issues however I cannot sit in an endless loop waiting for a user who may or may not be paying attention to clear up the issue on the screen.  It seems to cause the serial port to stop buffering data and just dropping it if it's not handled fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can protect the sheet with UserInterFaceOnly:=True.  This means the code can still write to the sheet.  [From this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protect%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y0) it looks like this is true with a VSTO addin as well.

Comment: I was already setting UserInterFaceOnly = true, however if the user has still tried to edit the form in some way, it throws up an error box that the user must click "OK" on before my code can continue to execute without throwing a COMException.

Answer (score 1):

You may put check to ensure sheet is in interactive mode or active cell is not null, if check fails exit function that perform write operation

```
 private bool IsExcelInteractive()
    {
        try
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive;
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing this operation on click of cell, can you add a button in ribbon and on its click do this task, this way will get rid of pop up window

Comment: The issue is that I'm performing tasks in the background without user intervention.  It is processing data coming in the serial port.  The data is unscheduled, so if the user is interacting with excel, e.g. has a cell open for editing (or is attempting to do so, but cannot since I have the cells locked) and the VSTO add-in tries to interact with Excel, the add-in fails in favor of the user.  See my answer for a trick that I came up with to solve this problem.